# python: converting two numbers to words

Tags: python, string, list

I have a program that currently takes two number and converts them into words in fraction from,
for example" frac(2,3) should return "two thirds", but I need help with the second input, in converting that to the word "third". right now something like frac (2,3) would return just "two" but I need it to return "two thirds"

my program:

```
def frac (numer, den):
    top = {'1': "one", '2': "two", '3': "three", '4': "four", '5': "five", '6': "six",
            '7': "seven", '8': "eight", '9': "nine", '0': "zero"}
    bottom = {'2': "half", '3': "third", '4':"Fourth",'5':"Fifth",'6':"sixth",'7':"seventh",'8':"eighth",'9':"ninth",'10':"tenth"}
    return " ".join(map(lambda x: top[x], str(numer)))
```

Comment: Tried using the num2words library?  https://github.com/savoirfairelinux/num2words

Answer (score 0):

No need for `join` nor `map`, just use `format`:

```
return '{} {}'.format(top[str(numer)], bottom[str(den)])
```

Comment: Or `return f'{top[str(numer)]} {bottom[str(den)]}'`

Comment: @PeterWood: It is really `numer` - as in numerator.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
def frac(numer, den):
    top = {'1': "one", '2': "two", '3': "three", '4': "four", '5': "five", '6': "six",
           '7': "seven", '8': "eight", '9': "nine", '0': "zero"}
    bottom = {'2': "half", '3': "thirds", '4': "Fourth", '5': "Fifth", '6': "sixth", '7': "seventh", '8': "eighth",
              '9': "ninth", '10': "tenth"}

    return f"{top[str(numer)]} {bottom[str(den)]}"


print(frac(2, 3))
```

Which yields

```
two thirds
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be an alternative approach making use of the fact that the values here can map directly to indices:

```
def frac(numer, den):

    if numer > 10 or numer <= 1:
        raise ValueError(f'Numerator must have value between 1 and 10 inclusive, got {numer}.')
    elif  den < 2 or den > 9:
        raise ValueError(f'Denominators only supported for values between 2 and 10 inclusive. got {den}.')

    numerator_words = ('one','two','three','four','five','six','seven','eight','nine',)
    denominator_words = ('half','third','fourth','fifth','sixth','seventh','eighth','ninth','tenth',)

    return ' '.join((numerator[numer-1], denominator[den-2]))
```

P.S. You might want to take a look at the [fractions module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) in the standard library.